# Ordering Figures and Images for Appendix

Tags: graphics, floats, appendix

I have 2 appendices, B & C. I have several images and tables that I wish to place under each appendix. However, having inserted all the relevant information, despite my best efforts all the images and tables are jumbled around and not in the correct order Tables B1 & B2 appear correctly under Appendix B however figures B3 to B10 while they appear in the correct order and are formatted correctly appear after C1 to C3. Table C4 appears after B3 to B10. 
If someone would be able to check my code and see where I am going wrong. This would be greatly appreciated. If any more information is required, I will be happy to provide.  Many Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{british}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Appendix}
\begin{appendices}
\begin{table}[!hbp]
\caption* {Table B1: Variable Definitions} \label{tab:title} 
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\textbf{Variable}     & \textbf{Definition}                                                                                                         \\ \hline
PRICE18      & IPL   2018 auction price.                                                                                          \\
LNPRICE18    & Natural   logarithm of IPL 2018 auction price.                                                                     \\
RESPRICE18   & Reservation   IPL 2018 auction price of a player.                                                                  \\
AGE          & The   age of a player, measured in years as of 26th January 2018.                                                  \\
ODIEXP       & The   number of One Day International (ODI) matches played.                                                        \\
ODIBATSR     & ODI   Batting Strike Rate. Calculated as the no. of runs per ball multiplied by   100.                             \\
ODIBOWLAV    & ODI Bowling Average. Calculated as the   no. of runs conceded by a bowler per wicket.                              \\
ODIBATRANK   & ICC ODI Batting Rank.                                                                                              \\
T20IBATAV    & T20I   Batting Average. Calculated as the total no. of runs per total no. of overs   faced.                        \\
T20IBOWLSR   & ODI Bowling Strike Rate. Calculated as   the no. balls bowled per wicket.                                          \\
T20IBOWLRANK & ICC   T20I Bowling Rank.                                                                                           \\
IPLEXP       & The   number of Indian Premier League (IPL) matches played                                                         \\
IPLBOWLAV    & IPL Bowling Average. Calculated as the   no. of runs conceded by a bowler per wicket.                              \\
IPLECON      & IPL   Economy Rate. Calculated as the no. of runs conceded per over bowled.                                        \\
IPLFIELD     & Total   no. of IPL Fielding Dismissals                                                                             \\ \hline
IND          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is Indian, 0 otherwise                                          \\
AUS          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is Australian, 0 otherwise                                      \\
SA           & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is South African, 0 otherwise                                   \\
ALL          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is an All-Rounder, 0 otherwise                                  \\
FAMOUS       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if the player has more than 1 million \\Instagram followers, 0 otherwise \end{tabular}         \\
FORLEAGUE    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if the player has played in a T20 tournament \\other than the IPL , 0 otherwise \end{tabular}  \\                 
SOLD         & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player was sold at auction, 0 otherwise                             
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}  
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!hbp]
\caption* {Table B2: Summary Statistcs} \label{tab:title} 
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l|lllll}
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Observations} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Std. Dev.} & \textbf{Min} & \textbf{Max} \\ \hline
LNPRICE18    & 186          & 5.0752  & 1.3618    & 3   & 7.44  \\
PRICE18      & 186          & 331.5   & 356.4     & 20  & 1700  \\
AGE          & 312          & 26.69   & 4.726     & 16  & 39    \\
FAMOUS       & 312          & 0.05448 & .2273     & 0   & 1     \\
IND          & 312          & 0.6346  & 0.4823    & 0   & 1     \\
AUS          & 312          & 0.1186  & 0.3238    & 0   & 1     \\
BAT          & 312          & 0.2051  & 0.4044    & 0   & 1     \\
ALL          & 312          & 0.3526  & 0.4785    & 0   & 1     \\
ODIEXP       & 312          & 30.19   & 55.87     & 0   & 312   \\
ODIBATSR     & 312          & 39.96   & 47.10     & 0   & 250   \\
ODIBOWLAV    & 312          & 15.20   & 25.37     & 0   & 172   \\
ODIBATRANK   & 312          & 58.33   & 15.59     & 1   & 65    \\
T20IBATAV    & 312          & 7.890   & 11.87     & 0   & 52.86 \\
T20IBOWLSR   & 312          & 7.269   & 11.42     & 0   & 68    \\
T20IBOWLRANK & 312          & 53.52   & 13.58     & 1   & 59    \\
IPLEXP       & 312          & 27.42   & 41.29     & 0   & 191   \\
IPLBOWLAV    & 312          & 12.64   & 18.29     & 0   & 90    \\
IPLECON      & 312          & 3.185   & 4.064     & 0   & 14.2  \\
IPLFIELD     & 312          & 9.087   & 16.64     & 0   & 90    \\
RESPRICE     & 312          & 139.2   & 241.4     & 2   & 1700  \\
FORLEAGUE    & 312          & 0.3397  & 0.4744    & 0   & 1     \\
SOLD         & 312          & 0.5961  & 0.4915    & 0   & 1    
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}  
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \setkeys{Gin}{width=1\textwidth}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B3}
  \includegraphics{example image 1}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B4}
  \includegraphics{example image 2}
 \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B5}
  \includegraphics{example image 3}
 \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B6}
  \includegraphics{example image 4}
 \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B7}
  \includegraphics{example image 5}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
 \caption*{Figure B8}
  \includegraphics{example image 6}
 \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \bigskip
  \begin{figure}[htb!]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[htb!]{1\textwidth}
   \caption*{Figure B9}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example image 7} 
  \caption*{*figure (right) shows the positive correlation for the upper tail of player valuations.}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{figure}[htb!]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[htb!]{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption*{Figure B10}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example image 8}
  \LARGE
  \caption*{*Outliers are marked in red with Mandeep Singh only having played a total of 3 T20I matches and Manoj Tiwary playing his last T20I in 2012.}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
 \vfill

 \section{Appendix}
 \newpage
 \begin{table}[htb!]
 \centering
 \caption*{\label{tab:table-name}\textbf{Table C1: Heteroskedasticity Tests}}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic   Specification}} \\ \hline
Breusch-Pagan/ Cook-Weisberg test*                  & Breusch-Pagan/ Cook-Weisberg test*                             \\ \hline
H0 : Constant Variance   (Homoskedastic)            & H0 : Constant Variance   (Homoskedastic)                       \\ \hline
$\chi$ ${}^{2\ }$   Test statistic = 9.42                         & $\chi$ ${}^{2\ }$   Test statistic = 13.61                                   \\
Probability = 0.0021                                & Probability = 0.0002                                          
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\label{tab:table-name}* The Breush-Pagan/Cook-Weisberg Test were carried out on the normal standard specifications. The null hypothesis of constant variance or homoskedastic can be rejected for both specifications.}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}[htb!]
  \centering
  \caption*{\label{tab:table-name}\textbf{Table C2: Misspecification Tests}}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic   Specification}} \\ \hline
Ramsey RESET test*                                  & Ramsey RESET test*                                             \\ \hline
H0 : Model has no omitted   variables               & H0 : Model has no omitted   variables                          \\ \hline
F (3, 169) = 12.64                                  & F (3, 169) = 8.82                                              \\
Probability = 0.0000                                & Probability = 0.0000                                          
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\label{tab:table-name}* The Ramsay Regression Equation Specification Error Test (RESET) tests whether non-linear combinations of the fitted values help explain the dependant variable, ‘lnprice18’. The null hypothesis of no omitted variables can be rejected for both specifications. }
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
  \centering
  \caption*{\label{tab:table-name}\textbf{Table C3: Tests for Endogeneity of the reserve price}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Regression of   generalised residuals on the reserve price*}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                            & GRESICCNR         & GRESRAWNR         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{RESPRICE18}                  & 0.0037            & 0.0036            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{CONST}                       & 4.37              & 4.42              \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{NO. OF OBSERVATIONS}         & 312               & 312               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\label{tab:table-name}* The dependant variables are the generalised residuals from the OLS ICC & Raw Statistic Specifications, respectively. These residuals are predicted based on each specification excluding the reservation price as an explanatory variable. The statistical significance, at the 1\% level, imply the reservation price of auctioned players is highly correlated with the residuals from the estimated models. As a result, a null hypothesis of no correlation between the estimated error and the reserve price can be rejected for both specifications. }
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}}                               & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic Specification}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix*}}                                & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix*}}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}          & GRESICCNR       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCR} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}           & GRESRAWNR       & GRESRAWR \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCNR} & 1               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESRAWNR}  & 1               &          \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCR}  & \textbf{0.8905} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESRAWR}   & \textbf{0.9235} & 1        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\label{tab:table-name}* The matrices show the correlation between the generalised residuals of the OLS specifications excluding the reserve price as an explanatory variable, ‘gresiccnr’ (‘gresrawnr’) and those when regressing the reserve price on all variables, except the reserve price itself. These results strengthen the case for base price being an endogenous variable.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb!]
 \centering
  \caption*{\label{tab:table-name}\textbf{Table C4: Correlation between residuals of Retained and Non-Retained Players}}
   \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}}                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic   Specification}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix*}}                                   & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix*}}                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}           & GRESICCNRT      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCRT} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}            & GRESRAWNRT      & GRESRAWRT \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCNRT} & 1               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESRAWNRT}  & 1               &           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESICCRT}  & \textbf{0.9701} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GRESRAWRT}   & \textbf{0.9917} & 1 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption*{\label{tab:table-name}* The matrices show the correlation between the generalised residuals of the OLS specifications, ‘gresiccrt’ (‘gresrawrt’) and the residuals excluding the 17 retained players ‘gresiccnrt’ (‘gresrawnrt’). These residuals are found to be highly correlated suggesting there is some unmodelled factor affecting both retained and non-retained players. As a result, the valuations, for retained players, cannot be excluded from the estimated models without having an impact on the estimated effects of all other variables. }

\end{table}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Missed are packages in preamble, `\begin{document}`. Also you have errors in tables. Inset tables in `adjustbox` is not good idea,  it make font in tables inconsistent.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?  Working mean complete with preamble (with required packages  as `adjustbox`, a `\begin{document}` and so on) and compilable as is. We do not have your images, so please change by `example-image` or other supplied by the mwe package (run  `texdoc mwe`  to see the options.). It also matters if there was  text among tables in the original document. You can add easily replace your text by dummy text of the package `lipsum`. BTW, my guess is that  forcing  floats position as (e.g., `[ht]` instead of `[htbp!]`) could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi, i have sorted out the ordering by addressing the floats issue so thanks for that. However, i still have a blank page before my charts and tables begin. Also how do I decrease the distance between the tables in my code? I would like to fit more than 2 on a page. I have tried the `\vspace{1cm}` many thanks

Comment: Also, while the order is the same I am unable to get my charts and figures to appear under their respective appendix headings? Any ideas why this may be

Comment: Probably not relevant, but both `caption` and `subcaption` are loaded more than once.  Regarding "distance between tables", you might try `\raggedbottom`.  Since there's nothing but figures or tables (and two section headers) on these pages, thers's nothing to fill up empty space, so the default `\flushbottom` will stretch out the spaces to make every page end at the same place.

Comment: Will there be anything other than these tables and figures in the two appendices?  If not, there's no need to make them float.  You can instead just input the `tabular`s and `\includegraphics` in order, with `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` as appropriate, use `\captionof` (from the `caption` package, which you're already loading), and insert spaces between them as needed.

Comment: Hi @barbarabeeton, yes there is another section to the appendix which is just text. It appears above the section I have listed.

Comment: Essentially, the two problems are: is that I have the header Appendix B, followed by a blank page and then another Appendix C header followed by another blank page and only then my charts and images appear in the order I would like. Also the other issue is reducing spaces between the tables, because at the moment they are spread out across 4 pages.

Comment: Blank page after Appendix B is consequence of `\newpage` after `\section{Appendix}`. Remove the. However, your tables design is strange. You may consider to use `threepartablex`  and use `tablenotes` instead of `caption*` after table body.

Comment: Hi @Zarko I will try your recommendation for the table design thanks. However, even after the removal of the newpage I still have the same problem with the headings?

Comment: Hello all, I have now addressed all the issues with your help. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Intention of MWE below is to serve as starting point how you can write your appendices. Since we haven't your images it may happen, that some figure will not fit in page. In this case, you probably should reorganize figures and change number of sub-figures in them. It is also unusual, that your figures haven captions (or it may be that I misunderstood, that you like to say with for example `\caption*{Figure B10}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}  % better is to use `geometry`
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25ex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % new
\usepackage[referable,flushleft]{threeparttablex} % new
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % new
\usepackage{chngcntr}   % new
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % new
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}%    new
    {\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont\RaggedRight}


\begin{document}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}
\section{Appendix}
\begin{table}[!hbp]
\caption{Variable Definitions} 
\label{tab:title}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|Xl}
\textbf{Variable}     & \textbf{Definition}                                                                                                         \\ \hline
PRICE18      & IPL   2018 auction price.                                                                                          \\
LNPRICE18    & Natural   logarithm of IPL 2018 auction price.                                                                     \\
RESPRICE18   & Reservation   IPL 2018 auction price of a player.                                                                  \\
AGE          & The   age of a player, measured in years as of 26th January 2018.                                                  \\
ODIEXP       & The   number of One Day International (ODI) matches played.                                                        \\
ODIBATSR     & ODI   Batting Strike Rate. Calculated as the no. of runs per ball multiplied by   100.                             \\
ODIBOWLAV    & ODI Bowling Average. Calculated as the   no. of runs conceded by a bowler per wicket.                              \\
ODIBATRANK   & ICC ODI Batting Rank.                                                                                              \\
T20IBATAV    & T20I   Batting Average. Calculated as the total no. of runs per total no. of overs   faced.                        \\
T20IBOWLSR   & ODI Bowling Strike Rate. Calculated as   the no. balls bowled per wicket.                                          \\
T20IBOWLRANK & ICC   T20I Bowling Rank.                                                                                           \\
IPLEXP       & The   number of Indian Premier League (IPL) matches played                                                         \\
IPLBOWLAV    & IPL Bowling Average. Calculated as the   no. of runs conceded by a bowler per wicket.                              \\
IPLECON      & IPL   Economy Rate. Calculated as the no. of runs conceded per over bowled.                                        \\
IPLFIELD     & Total   no. of IPL Fielding Dismissals                                                                             \\ \hline
IND          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is Indian, 0 otherwise                                          \\
AUS          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is Australian, 0 otherwise                                      \\
SA           & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is South African, 0 otherwise                                   \\
ALL          & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player is an All-Rounder, 0 otherwise                                  \\
FAMOUS       &  Dummy variable: taking the value 1 
                if the player has more than 1 million 

                Instagram followers, 0 otherwise        \\
FORLEAGUE    &  Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if the player has played in a T20 tournament other than the IPL , 0 otherwise         \\
SOLD         & Dummy variable: taking the value 1 if   the player was sold at auction, 0 otherwise
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hbp]
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:title}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|S[table-format=3]
                              S[table-format=3.4]
                              S[table-format=1.4]
                              S[table-format=2]
                              S[table-format=4.2]
                              @{}}
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Observ.} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Std. Dev.} & \textbf{Min} & \textbf{Max} \\ \hline
LNPRICE18    & 186          & 5.0752  & 1.3618    & 3   & 7.44  \\
PRICE18      & 186          & 331.5   & 356.4     & 20  & 1700  \\
AGE          & 312          & 26.69   & 4.726     & 16  & 39    \\
FAMOUS       & 312          & 0.05448 & .2273     & 0   & 1     \\
IND          & 312          & 0.6346  & 0.4823    & 0   & 1     \\
AUS          & 312          & 0.1186  & 0.3238    & 0   & 1     \\
BAT          & 312          & 0.2051  & 0.4044    & 0   & 1     \\
ALL          & 312          & 0.3526  & 0.4785    & 0   & 1     \\
ODIEXP       & 312          & 30.19   & 55.87     & 0   & 312   \\
ODIBATSR     & 312          & 39.96   & 47.10     & 0   & 250   \\
ODIBOWLAV    & 312          & 15.20   & 25.37     & 0   & 172   \\
ODIBATRANK   & 312          & 58.33   & 15.59     & 1   & 65    \\
T20IBATAV    & 312          & 7.890   & 11.87     & 0   & 52.86 \\
T20IBOWLSR   & 312          & 7.269   & 11.42     & 0   & 68    \\
T20IBOWLRANK & 312          & 53.52   & 13.58     & 1   & 59    \\
IPLEXP       & 312          & 27.42   & 41.29     & 0   & 191   \\
IPLBOWLAV    & 312          & 12.64   & 18.29     & 0   & 90    \\
IPLECON      & 312          & 3.185   & 4.064     & 0   & 14.2  \\
IPLFIELD     & 312          & 9.087   & 16.64     & 0   & 90    \\
RESPRICE     & 312          & 139.2   & 241.4     & 2   & 1700  \\
FORLEAGUE    & 312          & 0.3397  & 0.4744    & 0   & 1     \\
SOLD         & 312          & 0.5961  & 0.4915    & 0   & 1
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B3}
\includegraphics{IPL Nationality Breakdown (Full Data Set).png}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B4}
\includegraphics{IPL Nationality Breakdown (SOLD).png}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B5}
\includegraphics{graph1.png}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B6}
\includegraphics{graph2.png}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B7}
\includegraphics{example image 5}
\end{subfigure}%
      \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B8}
\includegraphics{IPL Bowling economy auction price.png}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
\caption*{Figure B9}
\includegraphics{insta.jpg}
    \begin{tablenotes}
\note{figure (right) shows the positive correlation for the upper tail of player valuations.}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.34\textwidth}
\caption*{Figure B10}
\includegraphics{relationship t20i batav auction price.png}
    \begin{tablenotes}
\note{*Outliers are marked in red with Mandeep Singh only having played a total of 3 T20I matches and Manoj Tiwary playing his last T20I in 2012.}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{Appendix}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Heteroskedasticity Tests}
\label{tab:B1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L|L @{}}
\textbf{OLS ICC Specification} & \textbf{OLS Raw Statistic   Specification} \\ \hline
Breusch-Pagan/ Cook-Weisberg test*                  & Breusch-Pagan/ Cook-Weisberg test*                             \\ \hline
H0 : Constant Variance   (Homoskedastic)            & H0 : Constant Variance   (Homoskedastic)                       \\ \hline
$\chi$ ${}^{2\ }$   Test statistic = 9.42                         & $\chi$ ${}^{2\ }$   Test statistic = 13.61                                   \\
Probability = 0.0021                                & Probability = 0.0002
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\note{The Breush-Pagan/Cook-Weisberg Test were carried out on the normal standard specifications. The null hypothesis of constant variance or homoskedastic can be rejected for both specifications.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{Misspecification Tests}
\label{tab:B2}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}
                & \textbf{OLS Raw Statistic Specification}  \\ \hline
Ramsey RESET test*  & Ramsey RESET test*                    \\ \hline
H0 : Model has no omitted   variables               
                    & H0 : Model has no omitted   variables \\ \hline
F (3, 169) = 12.64  & F (3, 169) = 8.82                     \\
Probability = 0.00  & Probability = 0.0000
\end{tabular}\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}
\end{center}
\begin{tablenotes}
\note{The Ramsay Regression Equation Specification Error Test (RESET) tests whether non-linear combinations of the fitted values help explain the dependant variable, ‘lnprice18’. The null hypothesis of no omitted variables can be rejected for both specifications.}
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Tests for Endogeneity of the reserve price}
\label{tab:B3}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|ll}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Regression of   generalised residuals on the reserve price*}} \\ \hline
    & GRESICCNR         & GRESRAWNR         \\ \hline
RESPRICE18                  
    & 0.0037            & 0.0036            \\
CONST                      
    & 4.37              & 4.42              \\
NO. OF OBSERVATIONS         
    & 312               & 312               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}
\end{center}
\begin{tablenotes}
\note{The dependant variables are the generalised residuals from the OLS ICC \& Raw Statistic Specifications, respectively. These residuals are predicted based on each specification excluding the reservation price as an explanatory variable. The statistical significance, at the 1\% level, imply the reservation price of auctioned players is highly correlated with the residuals from the estimated models. As a result, a null hypothesis of no correlation between the estimated error and the reserve price can be rejected for both specifications.}
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}

\clearpage
\section{Appendix}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Tests for Endogeneity of the reserve price}
\label{tab:C1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xll|Xll @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic Specification}} \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix}}    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix}}                \\ \hline
                & (1)   & (2)   &               & (3)   & (4)   \\ \hline
GRESICCNR (1)   & 1     &       & GRESRAWNR (3) & 1     &       \\
GRESICCR  (2)   & \textbf{0.8905} 
                        &       & GRESRAWR (4)  & \textbf{0.9235} 
                                                        & 1     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\note{The matrices show the correlation between the generalised residuals of the OLS specifications excluding the reserve price as an explanatory variable, ‘gresiccnr’ (‘gresrawnr’) and those when regressing the reserve price on all variables, except the reserve price itself. These results strengthen the case for base price being an endogenous variable.}
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Correlation between residuals of Retained and Non-Retained Players}
\label{tab:C2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xll|Xll @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS ICC Specification}}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{OLS Raw Statistic Specification}}    \\ \hline
%
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix}}    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Correlation Matrix}}                \\ \hline
                & (1)   & (2)   &               & (3)   & (4)   \\ \hline
GRESICCNRT (1)  & 1     &       & GRESRAWNR (3) & 1     &       \\
GRESICCRT  (2)  & \textbf{0.9701}
                        &       & GRESRAWR (4)  & \textbf{0.9917}
                                                        & 1     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\note{The matrices show the correlation between the generalised residuals of the OLS specifications, ‘gresiccrt’ (‘gresrawrt’) and the residuals excluding the 17 retained players ‘gresiccnrt’ (‘gresrawnrt’). These residuals are found to be highly correlated suggesting there is some unmodelled factor affecting both retained and non-retained players. As a result, the valuations, for retained players, cannot be excluded from the estimated models without having an impact on the estimated effects of all other variables.}
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

MWE produces five page long document. Each Appendix start on new page.